# fsockopen() returns different values on localhost and www server

Tags: php

```
$ping=fsockopen($ip, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

I am using the code above to ping some device.

When using a command line or running the code on my localhost, the device isn't answering; which is expected because the device can't send any package in answer.

However when I run the code on the www server that I've got, the fsockopen() returns TRUE.

Do you have any ideas why is it happening? Or how can I check if the device sends some package of data in response. I know that fsockopen() only check the connection.

Comment: You said you ping "some device". What is the value of `$ip` in your tests?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php), `fsockopen()` opens a connection and returns a `resource` (and not `TRUE`) when it succeeds.

There are many reasons why it does not work from your local computer. I can think about a couple but you can find the exact reason by checking the values of `$errno` and `$errstr` variables after the failing call returns.

Comment: It's good that it doesn't work from my local computer, I don't know why it works from the www, that's the problem, it shouldn't work. 
On local I get the errno=10060 and I want that result on the www too. May it be caused by the version of PHP? On the wampserver (localhost) I've got later version.

Comment: 10060 on Windows is [connection timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAETIMEDOUT). However, what is the value of `$ip`?

Comment: Have you tried type-comparing it with FALSE? i.e. if($ping === FALSE) ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. The result is !== FALSE (on the server), so it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: @pavon147, I was asking about the IP address because you said "some device". When I connect from my computer to "some device" (specifically, my phone) this happens through the local Wi-Fi network and both devices have private addresses (starting with 192.168). That could be a reason for different behavior (because the private addresses can be assigned to different devices in different networks) but it is not your case. The IP address you provided is not reachable from my computer. Maybe it is behind a firewall AND your server is on the same side of the firewall and it has access to it?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, but finally I use exec() function to properly ping this ip. Now it works good everywhere. I just don't have a time to deal with this problem longer, but it's interesting.